# Do you think it is important for generic type definitions to be derived from a non-generic type?

Tags: generics

Here is a simple example of a common problem:

```
   ICollection<int> myIntegers = ....
   ICollection<string> myStrings = ....
```

At some point, I pass instances of these and other
types to methods that receive them typed as IEnumerable.
(the non-generic form).

Without hacking through the back door via reflection,
that code cannot determine:

```
   1. That the instance is a constructed type of ICollection<T>

   2. The number of elements in the ICollection<T>-based type.
```

Without knowing what the generic argument is.

When I define  a generic type that provides operations
that have no dependence on the generic argument type
(e.g., like the Count property of ICollection), I
I generally define a non-generic base type and that is
where I put the non-type dependent operations, like so:

```
public abstract class FrugalList
{
   public abstract int Count {get;}
}

public class FrugalList<T> : FrugalList
{
   public override int Count {get{...}}
   void Add(T item) {...}
}
```

Given that, I can use the abstract base type
to get the Count of an instance of any type
constructed over the generic type definition, 
easily.

So, the question is quite simply, do you think 
it is important to provide this functionality
(which can also be done via interfaces) ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a problem of the method you call.

If that method asks for `IEnumerable`, it declares to the caller that it doesn't need more than what is provided by that interface.
If the method needs to know the Count it should just ask for the right interface, for example, become generic and be declared with a parameter of type `ICollection<T>`.

That is, no need to create "new" collection types when there are existing standard interfaces that do the job.

Comment: sorry to disagree. If you look at the implementation of Enumerable.Count() you might understand why. In short, my code will accept an IEnumerable, but if the object passed in is a collection, my code can optimize what it does based on the ability to get the number of items in the sequence in advance. – Tony Tanzillo 2 mins ago